# Newton-Raphson problem

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

> Consider the equation $\cos x = c$, where $c$ is constant. Find the value of $c$ so that the approximate solution by Newton-Raphson method at the $k$<sup>th</sup> iteration is $x_k = (-1)^k$, where $k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$.

Can anyone explain this problem? I can not understand what it mean or how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show what you've tried for solving the question in order to get help from the community instead of down votes :)

Comment: In addition to the answers which you have received it worth stress the thought behind the problem which you were given. The point is to teach you that Newton's method can enter into an infinite loop and never converge. In practice, it is the near occurrence of this phenomenon which slow's down the convergence. Your teacher seeks to make you remember the need for carefully constructing a good initial value $x_0$. Otherwise your software will not be reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Newton-Raphson method solves $\cos x -c=0$ by iterating $x\mapsto x+\frac{\cos x -c}{\sin x}$. We require this to map $1$ to $-1$, so $-1=1+\frac{\cos 1 -c}{\sin 1}$. Rearranging gives $c=\cos 1+2\sin 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton-Rhapson method is a numerical method that approximates the solutions to an equation $f(x)=0$ with a sequence $x_n$ defined recursively as $x_{n+1}=G_f(x_n)$, where $G_f$ is a function that can be written in terms of $f$ and $f'$ and $x_0$ is given. Its convergence theorem guarantees that, if $x_0$ is chosen inside some interval $[a,b]$ such that $f$ satisifies a few properties in it, then the sequence $x_n$ will converge to the only zero of $f$ in $[a,b]$.

Now, in your case, $x_0=1$ is given implicitly. Moreover, $f$ depends on the parameter $c$, and so do $G_{f_c}$ and the recursivey defined sequence $x^c_n$. The problem asks you to find $c$ such that $x^c_n=(-1)^n$.